# Install MySQL using MacPorts or Mac OS X binary package?

Tags: mysql, macos, macports

Is there any advantage in using one over the other? Should I use the [vendor provided](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mac-os-x-installation.html) PKG file or use the Darwin Ports version? Is there a general rule of thumb for deciding how to install a package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the vendor provided package just because of support.  I have found that when I have issues with darwinports it is much harder to find support than with PKG based installs.

Answer (score 3):

Use macports ( darwinports renamed ) .

You get a stock install that is in /opt/local.

Your toolchain built with this is very similar to the classic /usr/local toolchain you would get ordinarily in linux.  You know exactly how it's installed, and it pulls in dependencies automatically, and more to the point, it's quick to build the thing from source with any modern mac and when that is done then everything you need to build upon whatever it is is there, since you have the source.

port sync && port -d install mysql5 +server

if it's the first time using macports, run that at night and in the a.m. it'll be done.  Next time you wont need to build so much.  The system rewards constant use.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the vendor-provided package to install MySQL on OS X.  It was fast and easy.  For general-purpose MySQL usage, I don't see why anyone would do it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer using MacPorts to install software, *but* in the case of MySQL, I found it much easier to use the vendor-supplied installer. Less compile time (obviously), and it included tools that made configuration much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use a package from my package manager (though I use [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/)...). I have found that integration/dependency problems are more common and more severe than my bug-fix problems.

But, a lot will depend on the package maintainer, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use MacPorts or Fink for any critical apps.  Especially if you're using Leopard.

Perhaps it's just me, but I've had about a 50-50 success rate in installing apps using MacPorts and Fink.